# rails content-type for file_field uploads is incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, content-type

We have a file upload for pdf documents using the rails helper `file_field` in our system. We started with rails 2, and now rails 3 for about a year.

Looking in our database the pdf `content/type` is all over the place.

My understanding is it should always be `application/pdf`

but here is the list of types we have received:

```
application/x-octetstream
application/octet
application/x-download
binary/octet-stream
text/html
application/application/pdf
application/download
application/x-download
text/javascript
text/html
text/csv
```

The only work around I can see to set the content type correctly for now is to inspect the file body (something like this)

```
 if (upload_doc_name_ext == "pdf") && (incoming_file.content_type != "application/pdf") && (incoming_file[0..10].match(/%PDF-/) != nil)
    incoming_file.content_type = 'application/pdf'
 end
```

Any other ideas? Is this normal, is something else weird going on? Are the browsers behaving properly?

Comment: Are all the documents with those different values for `content_type` actually PDFs? Is there any validation on the incoming file that ensures only PDFs will be saved?

Comment: yep they are pdfs, I went through and checked them.

Comment: Out of curiosity - what problem is this incorrect content type causing?  The PDFs won't display or can't be downloaded or managed in some way?

Comment: We store the content type to figure out how to show it later and if to convert it or not. The work around works fine, but this seems like an html/rails bug.

Answer (score 2):

by default, rails form helper: `file_field` allows to upload all MIME filetypes so this is the reason why you have all those listed above.

In rails, if you use `file_field_tag` or `form.file_field`, you can specify the mime/content_type using `accept` option and list there all types user can upload.

`:accept` - If set to one or multiple mime-types, the user will be suggested a filter when choosing a file. You still need to set up model validations.

Source:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-file_field

Anyway, I suggest to use [paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and specify `content_type` validation then.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :document
  # Validate content type
  validates_attachment_content_type :document, :content_type => /\Aapplication\/pdf/
end
```

Paperclip would be easier to use and manage uploaded filetypes, it allow to adjust many oprions for uploading, so if you updated your application to Rails 3, it wolud be good solution for you.

Vote if it will help.

Comment: I think this would make things worse, not sure if you understood my question, but actual pdf's are coming through with other content types in production. If I validated on content_type then it would reject users uploading pdf's. Thanks and I am aware of paperclip gem, but I think this problem is related to how the html/browser is sending the file over to rails.

Comment: Sorry then. as you said, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: `:content_type => /\Aapplication\/pdf/` solved my problem. For some reason the `content_type: { content_type: ['application/pdf'] } ` code I've found everywhere else didn't work for me.